# Wordpress menu deletes when trying to add a hook

Tags: php, functions, menus, shortcode, widgets

I'm trying to customize the default Wordpress menus. Added this to my functions.php file and it makes my menus disappear. What is wrong?

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    $defaults = array(
        'container' => 'div'
    );
}

add_action('wp_nav_menu', 'custom_novice_menu');
```

Here is some documentation on [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's `wp_nav_menu` action. Perhaps you want the `wp_nav_menu` *filter* ([doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args))?

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    if( 'primary' == $args['theme_location'] ) // only apply to the right menu
    {
        $args['container'] = 'div';
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'custom_novice_menu');
```